# Is it possible to acess static html content in headless mode using HtmlUnit browser and Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, htmlunit

For example 
Initialisation of driver, and calling the page.

Webdriver is version 3.14 and HtmlUnit is 2.53.

```
 @Test
    public void testHtmlUnit(){
        HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
        driver.get("filePath.html");
    }
```

Error I am getting:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote   /SessionNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course; you have to do it the same way you will do it with the browser; simple use a file url like this:

```
url = "file:///C:/Users/someone/Desktop/htmlunit/test.html";
```

Regarding your exception:
NoClassDefFoundError usually points to a classpath problem. Please make sure you have all required classes in your path. And as always it is a good idea to use the latest version of the HtmlUnitDriver (2.39.0) and HtmlUnit (also 2.39.0) itself.